# jQuery Accordion /Tabs - Call different function upon load of content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following markup:

```
<body>
    <div id="tabs" style="float: left">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="ajax/question_0.html" title="Question 1"><span>Question 1</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="ajax/question_1.html" title="Question 2"><span>Question 2</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="ajax/question_2.html" title="Question 3"><span>Question 3</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="ajax/question_3.html" title="Question 4"><span>Question 4</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="ajax/question_4.html" title="Question 5"><span>Question 5</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="ajax/question_5.html" title="Question 6"><span>Question 6</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="dynamicContent">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="demo-description">
        <p>Click tabs to see answers to Questions</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

I would like to utilize an accordion or the tabs plugin from the UI.  Upon completion of the load event, I'd like to call a JavaScript function, but a different function for each tab -- almost like calling onDocumentReady for a page.

I have the following JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#tabs').tabs().bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
        console.log("Loading: ajax/question_" + ui.index + ".html");
        return true;    //Ensure that the tab gets selected
    });
);
```

That's properly loading the Ajax file and all, but whenever I attempt to do something such as evaluating a statement in the JS, it seems to be ignored.  Is there any way I can do this, so that once the file is loaded my function is called -- needs to be a different function for each tab.

Edit below:

Switching does in fact alleviate my problem of calling a different function.  I wasn't thinking...

However, what I'm after is having an empty div in each of these tabs which is used for logging (in case I'm in a web environment without Firebug).

I have the following function:

```
if (typeof console === 'undefined') {
    var console = { };
    console.log = function(msg) {
        $('#dynamicContent').append(createElement('p', msg));
    };
}
```

Which is supposed to log messages to a div which is loaded in each of the fragments, but none of the logging is done when a new tab is loaded.

My tabs are setup with the following:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({

    select: function(event, ui) {
        log.debug("Loading: ajax/question_" + ui.index + ".html");
    },

    show: function(event, ui) {
        log.debug("Finished Loading: ajax/question_" + ui.index + ".html");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not *exactly* what you're after, but there's a [`tabsload` event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-load) you can use, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#tabs').tabs().bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
    console.log("Loading: ajax/question_" + ui.index + ".html");
    return true;    //Ensure that the tab gets selected
  }).bind('tabsload', function(event, ui) {
    switch(ui.index) {
      case 0:
        //do something for first tab...
        break;
      case 1:
        //do something for second tab...
        break;
      //etc...
    }
  });
);
```

I used a [`switch` statement](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) for your "needs to be a different function for each tab", but whatever you need to do, call an external function, etc, you can do that here.  You can use `ui.tab` for the anchor element if you need to do a switch on the `href` for example, whatever fits best.